# baking and rendering with breaks in simulation, from lattice to cloth

Tags: physics, cache

I'm looking to animate/simulate/render physics that has gaps in simulation.  I'll start with Lattice/Soft-Body that then affects a large mesh.  But then looking a cloth sim its could get to be a rather large file and need smart ideas.

Motivation -- it's incredible difficult to get some simulations to be *calm* during periods of no action.   For example, when a character is standing still, the lattice with Soft-Body driving hair mesh movement continues to jiggle endlessly when it shouldn't, and similar for cloths on a character standing still.  Correct me if there's a way as I've done the hair-pulling exercise (on this author's own hair mesh)!   Perhaps there's a way to quell simulation during several ranges of frames?

I was hoping that multiple caches per simulation with stop/end frames that provide these gaps could accomplish this, but it appears that only the selected cache is used during a render operation for all frames (ctl-F12).  See the multiple caches on each Lattice in the attached file -- only the selected cache activates the object!   Oh yes I could pull more hair by scripting the render (render sets of frames, then switch selected caches on objects)....
[image]

With Lattice+SoftBody or Cloth,  I cannot apply multiple per object so that I could have several, one-cache simulations.

I suppose I could use several Lattice/Soft-Body on an object where I then use two Lattice modifiers with animated strength times during the appropriate period.

[image]

[image]

Or even a single lattice that might that simulates the full range of frames and just has multiple "on/off" strengths (might be a big jumpy, uses simulation memory that is ignored during render).

All in all I can find something relatively acceptable.

What about the cloth modifier?  I can only have a single cloth modifier.  This might mean a solution is to have several duplication of rather large object meshes, each with different ranges of simulation start/end.  Ouch!

I hope some more experienced advisors can throw a lifeline.